# Issue With Inheritance Class And CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I've create a abstract class "Shape",and its child class "Sphere"(implement all the functions).
Then I create a "Shape* my_sphere" point to "Sphere"(as follows):

```
Shape* my_sphere;
cudaMallocManaged(&my_sphere,sizeof(Sphere));
Shape* my_sphere_host = new Shphere;
cudaMemcpy(my_sphere,my_sphere_host,sizeof(Sphere),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

However when I use the "my_sphere" in a `__global__` or `__device__` function, cuda returned with the error code 700

```
__global__ testFunction(Shape* shape){
shape->getPosition();
}
```

could anybody help me?I'll appreciate it so much.

Comment: You have no other choice but to create it on the device, if you intend to use virtual methods. Otherwise you must drop inheritance and dispatch based on a type field in your own implementation.

Comment: then,I have to give up inheritance.......  :(       ,anyway thanks for reply

Comment: @Ext3h: that isn't necessarily true. Pass by value and pass by reference (given the class is allocated in managed memory) will both work *if the class doesn't violate any restrictions imposed by the CUDA object model*. However, there isn't enough details in the question to say what the actual problem is.

Comment: @talonmies Restrictions such as attempting to call virtual methods on the device, for an object created in host code? It works only for non-virtual methods, as RTTI and vtable are not portable.

Comment: Right, but who says there are virtual methods (I am guessing there are, but the question doesn't say)